# how to get last thursday of month in java

Tags: java, groovy

I have to fetch date of last Thursday of month of any year but the problem I'm facing is that for the `month of dec'15` last thursday is `31-dec-2015` but I'm getting `24-dec-2015` for the following code:

```
Date getLastThursday(def month, def year ) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set( year, month,1 )
    cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK )%7+2) );
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

And also explain me how this line of code internally works?

`cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK )%7+2))`

Comment: Did you take into account the fact that the month is 0-based? December is 11.

Comment: yes I checked that with every possible values.

Comment: yeah I have taken reference from there ony.

Comment: Since the month is 0-based so I changed that.

Comment: Explanation how that code works can be found [here](https://praveenlobo.com/blog/get-last-friday-of-the-month-in-java/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use Java 8+, you can use a temporal adjuster (part of the Java Time API):

```
int month = 12;
int year = 2015;
LocalDate lastThursday = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).with(lastInMonth(THURSDAY));
System.out.println("lastThursday = " + lastThursday); //prints 2015-12-31
```

Note: requires static imports

```
import static java.time.DayOfWeek.THURSDAY;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth;
```

---

If you can't use the new API, I suspect the problem is in the modulus operation and this should work:

```
//month should be 0-based, i.e. use 11 for December
static Date getLastThursday(int month, int year) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(year, month + 1, 1);
  cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 2) % 7));
  if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) != month) cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
  return cal.getTime();
}
```

The second if condition is there to make sure we have gone back one month.

Comment: I'm using java 7, so please tell me for Gregorian calender.

Comment: Hey this will work for dec only.

Comment: @user3666156 See my edit - it should be fine now (it works for all dates between 1900 and 2100).

Comment: @AMANKUMAR For Java 6 & 7, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, with much of the *java.time* functionality back-ported. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score -1):

Just put your modulus % outside:

```
cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK )+2)%7 );
```

if not, you get -8 => 24 december

and use month+1